# How can I use a string's value as an object's name?

Tags: c#, oop, object

**Hi.**
Is there any way, I can refer to an object with any string's value?

```
Classname person1 = new Classname("John");
Classname person2 = new Classname("Martin");
string getValue = "person1";
```

I've tried this: `Console.WriteLine(getValue.name);` and obviously it didn't work. :(
What could I do instead of this?

Comment: Perhaps it is better if you explain what is the problem that you are trying to solve with this approach.

Comment: Could you explain why you want this? I've never seen anything like this done before and frankly it seems like a bad idea whatever it's for except for maybe code analysis - but again you wouldn't hard code variable names in strings even then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store your instances of the `Classname` class into a dictionary under a string key:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Classname
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Classname(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // store class instance under a name to be referenced later
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, Classname>
        {
            ["person1"] = new Classname("John"),
            ["person2"] = new Classname("Martin"),
        };

        Console.WriteLine(dict["person1"].Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John
```

---

This *could* make sense if you have 1000s of names and want to retrieve the instance / check duplicates for special Classname instance by its `Name` in O(1) - you then put them into a dict under the same name as they get constructed with:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Classname>();

// use your list of names instead here
foreach (var nameNumber in Enumerable.Range(1, 2000))
{
    var name = $"Name_{nameNumber}";
    dict.Add(name, new Classname(name));
}

// dict provides O(1) access and O(1) check if already created 
// an instance with that name


// check if inside, do not retrieve
if (dict.ContainsKey("Name_155"))
    Console.WriteLine("Name_155 already constructed");

// check and retrieve, create + add if not there
var n = "Name_4000"
if (dict.TryGetValue(n, out var inst))
{
    // do smth with inst
}
else
{
    dict.Add(n, new Classname(n));
    inst = dict[n]; 
    // do smth with inst
}
```

Still feel it is quite a *constructed* example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
If you want to reference multiple enumerated Objects just create an array or a list with your objects.
for example

```
Classname[] classnames = {new Classname("..."), new Classname("...")};
```

you can then reference to them as `classnames[0]` and `classnames[1]`